# Who does the Fishman Island territory belong to?

Tags: one-piece

To whom does the Fishman Island territory belong to? First it was sure Whitebeard's territory. But what happened after he died? I thought Blackbeard took them all, because he knew them really well.

Or did Big Mama take this island?

Is Fishman Island is now Luffy's territory?

Comment: as far as the information goes we currently have is that big mom "owns/protects" the island. although they have a mugiwara flag just in case big mom decides to pull back that protection

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After Whitebeard's Death, the territory of Fishman Island belongs to Big Mam, who offers her protection in exchange of sweets from the island. It still belongs to her,
Luffy offered treasures to smooth out things with mama but she turned them down, but in the end decided to take care of things with Luffy instead of the fishman island.

The king of Fishman Island had said that maybe someday they will use another flag (that of the strawhats), but currently it still is Big Mam's territory.